Download CSV file in ReactJS Webview not working
My case is when user click on a button. A CSV file will be downloaded to their device.
const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);   
const link = document.createElement("a");   
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);   
link.setAttribute("download",`${fileName}.csv`);   
link.style.width = "0px";   
link.style.height = "0px";   
link.style.visibility = "hidden";   
link.style.position = "absolute";   
link.target = "_blank";   
document.body.appendChild(link);   
link.click();   
document.body.removeChild(link);

This is the function to download the CSV file. It only works on browser. But my mobile app (ReactJS Webview) it failed.
The error say : Failed to open URL data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Email%0A,,,: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=277, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}
Hopefully someone can tell my how to solve this problem. Thank you guys.

Instead of using a data URL, you can create a Blob and generate an object URL for it. This method is more compatible with mobile WebViews. Here’s how you can modify your function:
const csvContent = "FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Email\nJohn,Doe,1234567890,john.doe@example.com"; // Example CSV content
const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", url);
link.setAttribute("download", `${fileName}.csv`);
link.style.width = "0px";
link.style.height = "0px";
link.style.visibility = "hidden";
link.style.position = "absolute";
link.target = "_blank";

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);

URL.revokeObjectURL(url); // Clean up the URL object


If using Blob URLs doesn't solve the issue, you may need to implement a custom protocol or handler in your mobile app to handle the file download process. This approach can vary depending on the platform (iOS or Android) and the specific WebView implementation.
